# Align multiple equation to the first line

Tags: amsmath

I have multiple lines inside a single equation environment, with & align at =, but the whole "block" was center aligned by the longest equation.

What I want is center align the first line/equation, and align the rest by the first equation, how to achieve this?

```
\begin{equation*}
    \text{centered example line}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \cos^{-1}{x} &= \sin^{-1}{\frac{1}{3}} + \sin^{-1}{\frac{7}{9}} \\
    x &= \cos(\sin^{-1}{\frac{1}{3}} + \sin^{-1}{\frac{7}{9}}) \\
    &= \cos(\sin^{-1}{\frac{1}{3}}) \cos(\sin^{-1}{\frac{7}{9}}) - \sin(\sin^{-1}{\frac{1}{3}}) \sin(\sin^{-1}{\frac{7}{9}}) \\
    &= \sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{3})^2} \sqrt{1-(\frac{7}{9})^2} - (\frac{1}{3}) (\frac{7}{9}) \\
    &= \frac{1}{3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

this is what I get from the code above
[image]

and this is what I wanted to achieve
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For this, what you like to achieve is not enough space on page. try to write copy of the longest equation before its ampersand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is no left-hand material in any line but the first, what is requested can be accomplished easily by applying `\mathrlap` (`\usepackage{mathtools}`) to the right-hand side of all other lines:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \text{centered example line}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \cos^{-1}{x} &= \sin^{-1}{\frac{1}{3}} + \sin^{-1}{\frac{7}{9}} \\
    x &= \mathrlap{\cos(\sin^{-1}{\frac{1}{3}} + \sin^{-1}{\frac{7}{9}})} \\
    &= \mathrlap{\cos(\sin^{-1}{\frac{1}{3}}) \cos(\sin^{-1}{\frac{7}{9}}) - \sin(\sin^{-1}{\frac{1}{3}}) \sin(\sin^{-1}{\frac{7}{9}})} \\
    &= \mathrlap{\sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{3})^2} \sqrt{1-(\frac{7}{9})^2} - (\frac{1}{3}) (\frac{7}{9})} \\
    &= \mathrlap{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

However, as pointed out in a comment by @Zarko, lines with long right-hand sides might well exceed the right margin.  And if a document using this convention is submitted for publication to a journal with a narrower text width, it might either be sent back to you for modification or modified by the journal's production staff, opening it to the possibility that errors could be introduced.  Your choice.

Comment: I'm really new to TeX and this mathrlap solution is easier for me and works great, maybe there are some complicated stuff behind mathrlap but now I will just try to memorize it. Thank you, also Zarko, Mico, and egreg, I learned a lot  from your great answers.

Answer (score 5):

As @Zarko has already noted in a comment, your objective won't succeed in keeping the typeset material within the document's margins unless they are quite narrow. Even if it does fit -- see the use of `\hphantom` in the first `equation*` environment, again as per @Zarko's suggestion -- the resulting look is quite "off balance". I can't say it looks better than what's produced by centering the equation, as usual, in the available space.

Note that I've changed `\frac` to `\tfrac` throughout the first four lines of the five-line equation; the frame lines on the sides of the screenshot indicate the edges of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'equation*' and 'aligned' environments

\begin{document}
\begin{center} centered example line \end{center}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\cos^{-1}{x} &= \sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}} 
              + \sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}} \\
  x &= \cos\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}} 
     + \sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}}\bigr) \\
\hphantom{\cos\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}}\bigr) 
       \cos\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}}\bigr) 
       - \sin\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}}\bigr) 
         \sin\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}}\bigr)}
    &= \cos\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}}\bigr) 
       \cos\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}}\bigr) 
       - \sin\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}}\bigr) 
         \sin\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}}\bigr) \\
    &= \sqrt{1-\bigl(\tfrac{1}{3}\bigr)^2} \,
       \sqrt{1-\bigl(\tfrac{7}{9}\bigr)^2} 
       - \bigl(\tfrac{1}{3}\bigr) 
         \bigl(\tfrac{7}{9}\bigr) \\
    &= 1/3.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\cos^{-1}{x} &= \sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}} 
              + \sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}} \\
  x &= \cos\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}} 
     + \sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}}\bigr) \\
    &= \cos\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}}\bigr) 
       \cos\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}}\bigr) 
       - \sin\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{1}{3}}\bigr) 
         \sin\bigl(\sin^{-1}{\tfrac{7}{9}}\bigr) \\
    &= \sqrt{1-\bigl(\tfrac{1}{3}\bigr)^2} \,
       \sqrt{1-\bigl(\tfrac{7}{9}\bigr)^2} 
       - \bigl(\tfrac{1}{3}\bigr) 
         \bigl(\tfrac{7}{9}\bigr) \\
    &= 1/3.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\begin{center} centered example line \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but don't tell anyone:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}

\newcommand{\centertoplinetext}[3]{%
  \multispan{2}\makebox[\widthof{$\displaystyle#2#3$}]{#1\hspace*{\minalignsep}}\hfill\\
  #2&#3%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\centertoplinetext{centered example line}
  {\arccos x}{= \arcsin\frac{1}{3} + \arcsin\frac{7}{9}} \\
           x &= \cos\biggl(\arcsin\frac{1}{3} + \arcsin\frac{7}{9}\biggr) \\
             &= \cos\biggl(\arcsin\frac{1}{3}\biggr) \cos\biggl(\arcsin\frac{7}{9}\biggr)
              - \sin\biggl(\arcsin\frac{1}{3}\biggr) \sin\biggl(\arcsin\frac{7}{9}\biggr) \\
             &= \sqrt{1-\biggl(\frac{1}{3}\biggr)^{\!2}} \sqrt{1-\biggl(\frac{7}{9}\biggr)^{\!2}}
              - \biggl(\frac{1}{3}\biggr) \biggl(\frac{7}{9}\biggr) \\
             &= \frac{1}{3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\arccos` and `\arcsin` because I find `\cos^{-1}` and `\sin^{-1}` wrong from a mathematical point of view. Anyway, you don't need braces after `\cos`, `\arcsin` or similar commands. I also fixed the size of the parentheses.